# User input in PHP

Tags: php, html, web, xampp

Im new to PHP and I am trying to read user input in my code but im getting the error: Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN'

```
<?php 
    echo "<h1>Armstrong number</h1>";
    echo "Enter number: ";

   fscanf(STDIN, "%d", $input); //Error Line

    $n=$input;
    $sum=0;
    while($n != 0)   
   {   
       $rem = $n % 10;   
       $sum = $sum + $rem*$rem*$rem;   
       $n = $n / 10;   

   } 
    if ($input == $sum) 
    echo $input." entered is an armstrong no.";
    else
    echo $input." isnt an armstrong no.";
?>
``
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain that constant only exists when you use a CLI, is that what you are doing, or are you using this through a web browser?

Comment: I want to run this in a browser and ask for user input via browser. Is that possible ?

Comment: The web was never intended to be a bi-directional conversation. Instead, a browser requests a resource from the server, the server answers and then goes back to bed. If the browser wants to send more information, there's no continuation with the first "session", it starts all over. Over time, we have built abstractions and technologies that hide this, but at a fundamental level it doesn't exist. Fundamentally, if you want to ask a user for input, you put an HTML form on the page with one or more fields.

Comment: Oh okay thanks. Logically I knew it wasnt possible but just wanted to be sure

Comment: There are ways to mimic what you are going for, using AJAX/XHR, or WebRTC, but they are more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will check it out

Answer (score 0):

Because your conts "STDIN" isn't defined. For example, you can try this:

```
    $handle = fopen("your_file.txt", "r");
    
    define('STDIN', $handle);
```

and your code below

Comment: Is there a  different way to ask for user input on running in browser?

Comment: You can use this application - postman (https://www.postman.com/)

Comment: Isnt there a line of code solely for asking user input in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check Armstrong number through browser.

Run your code through CLI.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can run it via browser

Comment: You can use form input or query string